# Implementing merge sort in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, mergesort, irvine32

I am attempting to directly translate a merge sort algorithm from a higher level language (presumably java?) into MASM615. The implementation I am to translate is as follows:

```
// sort the subarray arr[i]..arr[j]
void mergeSort(int &arr, int i, int j)
{
if (i == j) return;          // terminating condition
int m = (i+j)/2;             // Step 1: compute the splitting point
MergeSort(arr, i, m);        // Step 2: sort the left part
MergeSort(arr, m+1, j);      // Step 3: sort the right part
Merge(a, i, m, j);           // Step 4: merge the sorted parts
}

// merge two subarrays arr[i]..arr[m] and arr[m+1]..arr[j] into a single array
// arr[i]..arr[j]
void merge(int &arr, int i, int m, int j)
{
int l = i;                   // left pointer
int r = m+1;                 // right pointer
int k = i;                   // index in the aux array

while((l <= m) && (r <= j))  // fill out the aux array
{
if (arr[l] < arr[r])       // take the minimum of arr[l] and arr[r]
{
aux[k] = arr[l];         // ... and put it into aux
l++;                     // update the left pointer
k++;                     // update the aux pointer
}
else
{
aux[k] = arr[r];
r++;                     // update the right pointer
k++;                     // update the aux pointer
}
}

while (l<=m)                 // put the rest of the left part to aux
{
aux[k] = arr[l];
l++;
k++;
}

while (r<=j)                 // put the rest of the right part to aux
{
aux[k] = arr[r];
r++;
k++;
}

for (k=i; k<=j; k++)  // save the changes in the original array arr
{
arr[k] = aux[k];
}
}
```

I believe that my implementation into MASM615 is copying this nearly exactly. However, The program hangs when being run. I tested the mergeSort procedure and it works perfectly. Therefore I presume there is some error in the merge procedure. However, I looked at it several times and find it to be an exact copy over, to the best of my knowledge. Here is my written code:

```
TITLE MASM Template                        (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
info1 BYTE "Array contents before mergeSort procedure:", 0
info2 BYTE "Array contents after mergeSort procedure: ", 0
arr DWORD -9, -64, -57, 81, 24
;, -98, 79, -59, -44, 19
    ;DWORD 52, -60, -51, -63, 23, -22, -37, 13, 88, 36
arrLen DWORD $ - arr
aux DWORD 5 DUP(0)

;variable definitions
a textequ <esi>
i textequ <eax>
j textequ <ebx>
k textequ <edi>
l textequ <ebp>
m textequ <edx>
r textequ <ecx>

.code

main PROC
;output original array
mov edx, OFFSET info1
call WriteString
call Crlf
call Crlf

push arrLen
push OFFSET arr
call printArr
call Crlf
call Crlf
call Crlf

;call mergeSort
mov eax, arrLen
shr eax, 2
dec eax
push eax
push 0
push OFFSET arr
call mergeSort

mov edx, OFFSET info2
call WriteString
call Crlf
call Crlf
push arrLen
push OFFSET arr
call printArr

ProgEnd:
call Crlf
exit
main ENDP

merge PROC USES eax ebx ecx edx esi edi ebp
;take in params. High level code conversion:
;  * i = eax   | * &arr = esi
;  * m = edx   |   k = edi
;    r = ecx   |   l = ebp
;  * j = ebx
;  NOTE: '*' means that the value is passed into the process.

mov a, [esp + 32]
mov i, [esp + 36]
mov m, [esp + 40]
mov j, [esp + 44]

;calculate additional variables: ecx, edi, ebp
mov l, i
mov k, i
mov r, m
inc r

;while loop 1 of 3
While1:
cmp l, m
jg afterWhile1
cmp r, j
jg afterWhile1

;if cond1 && cond2 (need to push pop eax and ebx to compare
;since we are out of general use registers!
push ebx
push eax
mov eax, [a + 4 * l]
mov ebx, [a + 4 * r]
cmp eax, ebx
jge While1_else


;do "if condition success" commands
mov eax, [a + 4 * l]
xchg [aux +  4 * k], eax
inc l
inc k

;restore registers
pop eax
pop ebx

jmp While1

While1_else:
;do "if condition failure" commands
mov eax, [a +  4 * r]
mov [aux + 4 * k], eax
inc r
inc k

;restore registers from above
pop eax
pop ebx

jmp While1

afterWhile1:
;push eax for popping later after BOTH the
;second and third while loop.
push eax

;while loop 2 of 3
While2:

;terminating condition
cmp l, m
jg While3

mov eax, [a + 4 * l]
mov [aux + 4 * k], eax
inc l
inc k
jmp While2

;final While loop
While3:

;terminating condition
cmp r, j
jg afterWhileLoops

mov eax, [a + 4 * r]
mov [aux + 4 * k], eax
inc r
inc k
jmp While3

afterWhileLoops:
;pop eax, since we are done with
;while loops 2 and 3.
pop eax

;set k = i
mov k, i

forLoop1:
;check if k <= j]
cmp k, j
jg endMergeProc

;sacrifice the value of m (edx), since we are
;not using it, nor will need it in the future.
mov m, [aux + 4 * k]
mov [a + 4 * k], m

inc k
jmp forLoop1


endMergeProc:
ret 16
merge ENDP

mergeSort PROC USES eax ebx edx esi
;take in params
mov a, [esp + 20] ;array address
mov i, [esp + 24] ;begin of merge
mov j, [esp + 28] ;end of merge

;return condition: start and end are equal.
cmp i, j
je endMergeSort

;edx = midpoint of eax, ebx
mov m, i
add m, j
shr m, 1

;do recursion part 1.
push m
push i
push a
call mergeSort

;do recursion part 2.
inc m
push j
push m
push a
call mergeSort

;call merge fn (&a, i, m, j)
dec m
push j
push m
push i
push a
call merge

endMergeSort:
ret 12
mergeSort ENDP

printArr PROC USES esi eax ebx ecx
mov esi, [esp + 20] ;array address
mov ecx, [esp + 24] ;array length
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx

printElements:

cmp ebx, ecx
jge endPrintArr

mov eax, [esi + 1 * ebx]
call writeInt
mov al, ' '
call writeChar
add ebx, 4
jmp printElements

endPrintArr:
ret 8
printArr ENDP

END main
```

Note that I commented out part of the original array. The length would be 20 in the end, but I would like to get it working properly with 5 first! ;) I've looked at my code over and over and don't see my error. What have i done wrong?

Edit: realized that I was still thinking higher level language sometimes! In a higher level language, you increase your array index by 1. In assembly, you need to increment the index by 4, taking account for the size of each element. These changes are reflected in the code above now, but it still doesn't work!

Comment: I only skimmed through the code; but I don't see how you'd ever end up executing the `push` right before `While2:`. So it seems to me like the `pop` at `afterWhileLoops` will unbalance the stack.

Comment: Indeed! Let me make sure that is reached, and perhaps this will fix it. :)

Comment: I added a new label "afterWhile1", and used it to reach the mentioned code at the termination condition of the first while loop. The change can be seen in my original post! However, this clearly does not sort the array. Running the current code you get BEFORE: -9, -64, -57, +81, +24 .... and AFTER: -2112, -16129, -57, +81, +24. It is not only NOT in order, but some of the values after are not in the original array! Thanks for spotting the stack imbalance though!!! :D

Comment: realized a fundamental error in the way i was incrementing array indexes, code is updated in original post but still doesn't fully work.

Comment: Looks like you've still got some inconsistencies between values being scaled by 4 for DWORD addressing, and not being scaled by 4. To make things easier I'd suggest going back to incrementing them by 1, and only scaling them by 4 in the actual memory accesses (e.g. `mov eax,[a + l*4]`).

Comment: Code Updated. I added a printout of the array after the function call. I also made the tweak suggested by Michael, since it seemed to be the best way to make the code easy to read. The program now takes SOME steps in the right direction, but still only seems to swap a couple values. The good thing is that there are no strange values coming up out of nowhere.

Comment: The two memory accesses after `;do "if condition success" commands` need to have their indices scaled as well.

Comment: Apologies Michael. I did scale them in my code, but somehow missed them when updating what the code was here on stack overflow. This is now corrected, but it still wont sort properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had incremented "m" for the equivalent of the high-level call "MergeSort(arr, m+1, j);", but when i then had to do "Merge(a, i, m, j);" i had forgotten that this m is really the value i needed +1. I have now decremented m again in the code just before the second call, and that fixed it! The code written in the question is now correct!